# Algorithm for generalized Hilbert's Theorem 90 over $\Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-groups, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

$\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\Bbb R}}
\newcommand{\C}{{\Bbb C}}
$For a natural number $n$, let $z\in \GL(n,\C)$ be a 1-cocycle
of $G=\GL_{n,\R}\,$, that is,
an invertible complex matrix such that
$$z\cdot\bar z=1$$
where the bar denotes complex conjugation.
By a generalization of Hilbert's Theorem 90,
we have $H^1(k,\GL_n)=1$ for any field $k$, and in particular,
$H^1(\R, \GL_n)=1$.
It follows  that there exists an element
$g\in\GL(n,\C)$ such that
\begin{equation}\label{e:1}
 g^{-1}\cdot \bar g =z,\quad\text{that is,}\quad \bar g =g\cdot z.\tag{$*$}
\end{equation}

For example, let $n=2$, $z=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.
Write $g=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$.
Then \eqref{e:1}  gives
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \bar a&\bar b\\ \bar c&\bar d\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} b&a\\d&c\end{pmatrix},$$ that is, $b=\bar a$ and $c=\bar d$. Thus
$$  g=\begin{pmatrix} a&\bar a\\ \bar d&d\end{pmatrix}.$$
We choose  $a=1$, $d=i$, and we obtain
\begin{equation}\label{e:2}
 g= \begin{pmatrix} 1& 1\\  -i&i\end{pmatrix}.\tag{$**$}
\end{equation}

> **Question.** I need an algorithm that, for given $n$ and
> a 1-cocycle $z\in \GL(n,\C)$,  will give $g\in\GL(n,\C)$ satisfying \eqref{e:1}.
> Moreover, I want the algorithm to give a *nice* element $g$.
> For example, for $z=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, I want to get
> something like \eqref{e:2}.

**Remark.** We (my coauthor and I) already  have
an algorithm and a computer program for this problem.
However, for $z$ as above, our program gives
\begin{equation}\label{e:3} \tag{$*{*}*$}
\begin{pmatrix} \frac12+i&\tfrac12-i\\ \tfrac12-i&\tfrac12+i\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
which I like less than \eqref{e:2}.

Comment: This seems hard to answer without knowing what a "nice" element is (or, perhaps equivalently, how much you like which elements).

Comment: @LSpice:  My cocycle $z$ lives in the stabilizer $H_t$ of a real tensor $t$. I use $g$ in order to obtain a twisted form $t'=g\cdot t$ of $t$.  An easy calculation shows that $t'$ is again real: $\overline{t'}=t'$. My original tensor $t$ has all coefficients equal to 0 or 1 only. I want to obtain $t'$ with small coefficients, if possible with coefficients 0, $1$, and $-1$ only (up to a scalar). This works with \eqref{e:2}, but not with \eqref{e:3}.

Comment: In the context of the question, what are the $t$ and $t'$ in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435791/algorithm-for-generalized-hilberts-theorem-90-over-bbb-r#comment1122797_435791)?

Comment: Actually I consider the group ${\rm GL}_{5,\Bbb R}\times {\rm GL}_{4,\Bbb R}$ acting on the vector space $\bigwedge^2 {\Bbb R}^5\otimes {\Bbb R}^4$.  My cocycle $z$ is a real block-diagonal matrix consisting of  2-dimensional blocks \eqref{e:1}, one-dimensional blocks 1, and a one-dimensional block $-1$.